# UIImage works on simulator but crashes on device swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I have checked UIImage works on the simulator but not working on the device.
Here's the code:

```
imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
let image = UIImage(named: "sample.png")
imageView.image = image
view.addsubview(imageView)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What's the reason of the crash? what the log told you?

Comment: No displays on the log. But the image doesn't show.

Comment: so the app does *not* crash, the issue is the imageview doesn't contains an image right?

Comment: This imageView shows when I tap the button, but when I tap the button it doesn't work. I think there's problem in `imageView.image = image`.
I have checked `UIImageView` is working.

Comment: i am a bit confused when you say "imageView shows when I tap the button, but when I tap the button it doesn't work"

Comment: Mentioning "crashes" in the question could confuse the viewers, that's what happened to me :) you might need to let it "doesn't work" or something...

Comment: Remember that real iOS devices use case sensitive file names.

Comment: I know that and named correctly. The name doesn't related.

Comment: Please crash error log also display here so we can see what is the reason behind this crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extremely larger images bigger than UIImageView size causes the crash. UIImageView size is 50 x 50, but the image size is 900 x 900. This works on simulator but doesn't work on iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your image to 'Copy Bundle Resources'.

Select Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources and add your image to the list.

[image]

Comment: I have already image in 'Copy Bundle Resources'.
I think this is not related.